# 1 click undo on photoshop actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Ive been using some Photoshop actions (not developed by me) to add a 'grunge' effect to some text (a .png), it works well but theres several levels of grunge, so i tend to try a couple out to see which ones i like.

The problem is when i try one that i dont like i want to just hit undo and revert back to how the image was before, but instead it just undos 1 level of the script ie. if the script said do `process 1, then 2, then 3` and i then clicked undo it would only undo step 3 not the whole script.. is there a way to change this ?

Background - im using CS5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There's no way to change it.

You could simply look at the **History Panel** and click the step before you ran the script. Or, create snapshots (via History panel menu) and then click the snapshot you want.

Answer (score 2):

If it is always a 3 step process, you could make an action with 3 undos and map that to a hotkey.

Otherwise you could do it in scripting also.